# WizardPager Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using [WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager) in my app. Once I select item from review page app crashes with `Illegal State Exception: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions` I have googled a lot about it, but no solution found.

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.